# Managing Unicode in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, unicode

I have SQL Server with collation set to `Latin1_General_CI_AS`. Now the problem is while importing users into the system duplicate entries make their way into the database for those records who have trailing Hyphen-Minus which appears only in SQL Server window, but vanishes on browsers and notepads and even if I put them under single quotes.

You will notice that first will return two records of same `EmailId`, but the second will return only one record which have same `EmailId` in where clause returned by the first script.

When you copy the emails from the first script in notepads or browsers or emails they appear same but when you copy it in SQL Server itself you can see trailing Hyphen-Minus.

These users imported into the system because of these unicode which are treated as a unique record by the SQL Server and allowed entry into the system.

How can I distinguish these records and prevent them entering into the system?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unicode values should be placed in a NVARCHAR column, which takes 2 bytes per character, in contrast to VARCHAR which only takes 1. If you don't want unicode characters, you should convert the values to VARCHAR but keep in mind that you might lose data, since characters not available in 1-byte representation will be lost. SSMS grid view does a ninja replace and hides some characters that are actually stored in the column, like new lines or tabs.

First step would be checking which data type is you Email column. It is probably NVARCHAR. When you write a hard-coded NVARCHAR value you need to place an "N" just before the string like this:

```
EMail = N'myEmail@email.com'
```

If you want to check the exact contents of a string, you can see its hexadecimal representation and see which leading weird character is has. Try this out for the 2 records with the "same" email:

```
SELECT convert (varbinary, Email) FROM UserInfo.[User]
```

Unfortunately the solution would involve cleaning these characters. Casting them to VARCHAR (if they are NVARCHAR) might solve some, but not all, as you could still have for example a `TAB` character at the start of you value.

You can try to search for them using a LIKE similar to this one (returns all emails that are NOT letters from A to z, numbers, dots or at):

```
SELECT U.Email FROM UserInfo.[User] AS U WHERE U.Email LIKE '%[^A-z0-9@.]%'
```